# How can I organize this multi-threaded application so that it doesn't get stuck "waiting" for locks?

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization

(UPDATE: I got some good ideas to try in answers and comments-- gonna start trying stuff this week and update again when something works!)

This is one I've been struggling with for a while. I have a C++ class that has a number of public functions, and it's expected that each of these functions will be called from different threads at regular intervals. The basic form of the class is something like this:

```
class DataProcessor
{
public:
    void process1(...);
    void process2(...);
    void process3(...);
    // etc...

    void update();
};
```

In case it matters, this is a robotics application and each of the "process" functions are for taking in data from different sensors, so any time new sensor data comes in we call the appropriate "process" function in its own thread. The "update" function is used in a loop that looks something like this:

```
while(true) {
   wait 1 second;
   dataProcessor.update();
}
```

Now, I have it set up so that each of the "process" functions can be called concurrently without any problems, but the "update" function should NOT be called while any of the "process" functions are executing. The update function is fairly quick and executes in almost no time at all, while some of the process functions are kind of expensive and can take on the order of 0.1-0.2 seconds.

So far I've tried two strategies for making this execute safely, but both strategies resulted in functions spending too much time blocking/waiting for mutexes ("mutices"?) to be unlocked.

The first thing I could do was have each "process" function lock and unlock its own mutex at the beginning and end of execution, and then the "update" function has to own *all* of them in order to execute. When I do that, though, I get issues like the following:

1. The "process1" function finishes and unlocks mutex 1
2. The update function locks mutex 1, and is waiting for mutex 2 to be unlocked
3. The "procees1" function gets called again, but has to wait for the update function to unlock mutex 1
4. The update function can't unlock mutex 1 until it finishes executing, which it can't do yet because it's waiting for all the other "process" functions to finish

So now the "process1" function is effectively having to wait for all of the other "process" functions to finish, even though the process functions are designed to be able to run concurrently.

So the other strategy was to use a counter. Basically a "numberOfFunctionsRunning" variable, so each of the "process" functions can increment the variable at the start and decrement at the end. And then the update function can only execute when that variable is at zero. This is a little better, since now the process functions can execute concurrently again, but now the update function waits forever since the variable rarely reaches zero.

So yeah, I hope this is enough information and it makes sense what I'm trying to do. Is there any threading strategy I can use to make sure that the "process" functions can execute without spending a lot of time waiting, while also making sure that the update function can execute at regular intervals?

Comment: Are you looking for `std::shared_mutex`?

Comment: "_but now the update function waits forever since the variable rarely reaches zero._": So in other words there aren't sufficient time windows where `update` can run anyway. Then the first question would be whether `update` is more important than `processX` and should be able to either make them wait or even interrupt them (via interrupts or signals)?

Comment: BTW, the pattern you're looking for is called reader-writer locks. (RW locks). This is a well-known problem in scheduling. One of the reasons why there is no single standard solution is because the best strategy depends on the underlying problem. Robotics specifically sounds like a real-time problem, where the optimization criterion is not simply "fastest completion of program". You can't simply time how long `main` takes to complete.

Comment: Can you use a lock-free approach?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/ORESoftware/live-mutex/blob/dev/docs/write-preferring-rw-lock.md) help?

Comment: Okay-- sounds like I've got some ideas to try (some of these concepts I hadn't heard of before). I'll go through these ideas this week!

Comment: I would probably implement the 'update' loop as a wait on a producer-consumer queue and have the various 'process' threads queue updates.  The more locks, the more likely the deadlocks and/or poor performance.  I try very hard to restrict locks to the queue mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to get something I'm mostly happy with by combining a couple different approaches that were in the comments to the original question. This link (https://github.com/ORESoftware/live-mutex/blob/dev/docs/write-preferring-rw-lock.md) was really helpful and got me most of the way there-- the key is that while it's probably not possible to make this work with absolutely zero delays from locking, you can kind of come close if you allow the "update" function to block for only a "short" period of time (for some definition of "short").

So, to do this, I add the following member variables to the DataProcessor class:

```
std::mutex updateMutex;
std::condition_variable updateCondition;
bool updateWaiting;
unsigned int workersRunning;
```

Then, add this code block at the top of each "process" function:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> updateLock(updateMutex);
while (updateWaiting) { updateCondition.wait(updateLock); }
++workersRunning;
updateLock.unlock();
```

I think this is pretty much identical to the "lock for read" operation in that page I linked to.

The end of each of the "process" function is basically the "unlock for read" operation from that page:

```
updateLock.lock();
--workersRunning;
updateLock.unlock();
updateCondition.notify_all();
```

Then, for the "update" function I add code that's *almost* like the lock-for-write and unlock-for-write operations in that link, except that it's only allowed to block for up to 50 milliseconds. This means that the update function might not always execute, so I compensate for that by calling it more often than the once per second that I originally had:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> updateLock(updateMutex);
auto currentTime = now();
updateWaiting = true;
while (workersRunning > 0) {
    if (updateCondition.wait_until(updateLock, currentTime + milliseconds(50)) == cv_status::timeout) {
        break;
    }
}

updateLock.unlock();
if (workersRunning == 0) {
    // Do the actual work
}

updateWaiting = false;
updateCondition.notify_all();
```

Basically what this does is allow the update function to say "I'll wait for any current processes to finish, but nobody start any new work right now because I gotta get in there and do my thing real quick." But then, if it ends up waiting for more than 50 milliseconds, it says "Okay, never mind, I'll get to it next time I'm called."

So then it's just a little bit of experimentation to determine how often should update be called and how long should it wait. It's not a 100% perfect solution, but there probably isn't one and this at least works well enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can lock all the mutexes atomically(ish) using [std::lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) like this:

```
class DataProcessor
{
public:
    void process1()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m1);

        // do stuff here
    }

    void process2()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m2);

        // do stuff here
    }

    void update()
    {
        // use std::defer_lock to hold off the locking
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(m1, std::defer_lock);
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock2(m2, std::defer_lock);

        std::lock(lock1, lock2); // lock all mutexes atomically

        // do stuff here
    }

private:
    std::mutex m1;
    std::mutex m2;
    std::mutex m3;
};
```

This way the locks in `void update()` will only take effect when *none* of the other functions are holding the locks, avoiding the deadlock.

Comment: Or just `std::scoped_lock`. But that isn't atomically, it just avoids deadlocks. This will still make `process1` potentially wait for other `process` completions without running `update`, which OP seems to have an issue with. (But then they also have an issue with having `update` wait too long. Not sure what the priorities are supposed to be.)

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, indeed. I avoided `std::scoped_lock` because it is more recent `c++17` whereas `std::unique_lock` has been available since `c++11` but it's definitely another, perhaps neater, solution.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it! I hadn't heard of this before.